# What are support values in a support vector machine?

Tags: machine-learning, terminology, definitions, support-vector-machine

I started reading up on SVM and very little is defined of what are support values. I reckon it's they are denoted as $\alpha$ in most formulations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the least-squares SVM (LS-SVM) the non-zero Lagrange multipliers ($\alpha$) are the support values.  The corresponding data points are the support vectors.  Johan Suykens explains this in [Least Squares Support Vector Machines](https://www.esat.kuleuven.be/sista/natoasi/suykens.pdf).